# Checking array of editText is empty

Tags: android, arrays, methods, android-edittext

I made this code to check if any of the edit texts are empty. I place them all in an array and then check each one to see if it was empty. If there's an empty one, a toast shows. If all are not empty, the app continues. The problem is, my method is queuing all the edit text and its freezing the toast on the app. How can I fix this problem?

My array inside a button onCreate:

```
            final EditText[] editTextArray = new EditText[] {
                    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1),
                    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2),
                    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num3),
                    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num4),
                    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num5),
                    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num6),
                    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num7),
                    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num8),
                    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num9),
                    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num10),
                    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num11),
                    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num12),
                    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num13),
                    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num14),
                    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num15),
                    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num16),
            };
```

loop:

```
for (EditText anEditTextArray : editTextArray) {
                checkTextInput(anEditTextArray);
            }
```

the method:

```
private boolean checkTextInput(EditText input) {

    String inputNum = input.getText().toString();

    if (inputNum.isEmpty()){

        // Toast message
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The board is missing numbers.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

    } else {

        Log.i(TAG, "working");
        return false;
    }

} // end checkTextInput
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your for loop like this

```
for(EditText anEditTextArray : editTextArray) {
    if(checkTextInput(anEditTextArray)) {
        // an edit text is empty, so we need to stop the for loop to prevent lots of toast being shown on screen if there are more empty edit texts
        break;  // or use return based on the logic of your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize Toast outside checkTextInput and cancel it before show. So it will stop previous one and show the new one.

```
Toast t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The board is missing numbers.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    private boolean checkTextInput(EditText input) {

        String inputNum = input.getText().toString();

        if (inputNum.isEmpty()){

            // Toast message
            t.cancel();
            t.show();
            return true;

        } else {

            Log.i(TAG, "working");
            return false;
        }

    } // end checkTextInput
```